# django: linking contact form with file uploads and recaptcha

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am working on a small blogging app for myself using Django, and I have introduced a file upload facility using https://github.com/GoodCloud/django-ajax-uploader .I have managed to make it work, and the file uploads seems to be working fine.

I would now like to add a (contact) form alongside the file upload, but I am unsure how to 'link' the form to the file uploads. So, my logic is that the user fills in the contact form, and then upload the files (and then obviously presses the "submit"). My question (not sure if I am making this clear), is that how do I make a link between the contact form contents (such as name, email id etc..) to the files the user has uploaded using django-ajax-uploader. What would be the most efficient way to do this?

If it helps, I plan to write the (contact) form using modelForms, which would obviously write the fields to the database. However, django-ajax-uploader does not use a db, and therefore, I am not sure how I could link the both. Addionally, I have included recaptcha in my modelform using the instructions on: http://www.marcofucci.com/tumblelog/26/jul/2009/integrating-recaptcha-with-django/ I see the recapatcha, but I am not sure that my function fileup processes the form.

Any guidance on this would be great. Thanks.

Updated Code is on: http://dpaste.com/750619/

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding about your goal, it seems that the only thing that connecting your uploaded file in the server and your form is the response returned by the file uploader itself.

You must catch the uploaded filename and set it to the hidden file on your form when you get the response from your ajax file uploader.

Your form might look like this:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField()
    email = forms.EmailField()
    the_file = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())
```

And in Javascript code of your file add into this section:

```
...
...,
onComplete: function(id, fileName, responseJSON) {
    if(responseJSON.success) {
        //Note that i add "id_" in front of field name, because django automatically add this when rendering the form.
        $('#id_the_file').val(fileName);
     } else {
        alert("upload failed!");
    }
},
...
...
```

That way at least now you have file name into the form when user submit your contact form.

Now its your job to get the full URL of the file when sending the email, because so far we have only the file name, not the full file url on your server.

then you can provides its as a link or an attachment in your mail.

I hope it helps :) and sory for my bad english...

Comment: Hi ekaputra, I have updated my post with a bit of code. Would really appreciate if you could take a look at it and let me know!

Answer (score 1):

The only way you can show the file upload button in your contact form is by its template, you need to edit the template like this:

```
<form action="/contact/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}

{{ form.as_p }}

<!-- this block is required to show file upload button --->
<div id="file-uploader">       
   <noscript>          
       <p>Please enable JavaScript to use file uploader.</p>
   </noscript>         
</div>
<!-- end file upload button-->

<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

when you click the submit button and when you upload a file, they are in different request. Your submit form will be handled by "**fileup**" function in your view, and file upload handled by "**import_uploader**", and you can't make this request at the same time.

To make your Contact model also saving the file name, then you must:

1. Do file upload first (**File Uploader POST request**).
2. get the file name returned by ajax file uploader, and set this value to
   your "**fnames**" field.(by using js/jquery technique in my last
   comment). But in this case, your "**fnames**" field will be rendered as a textfield. that's why I use HiddenInput in my last code, so it does not need to be visible but it's there.
3. now you can continue click the form submit button, your form will
   submitted with filename in it. (**Contact Form POST request**)

Because **fnames** in your model is required, you must make sure that user already upload a file before submitting the entire form.

Comment: thanks for this, I am still trying to understand clearly what is going on. In my "fileup" view function, should I have "if request.method == 'POST':" line? If I uncomment it, my form is not visible anymore.

Comment: I have updated my code now, as above and its on dpaste. I have used the hidden field using exclude field in modelform. However, I have one complexity in that I have also included recaptcha. Now, I have a form with a file upload and recaptcha, and I was wondering how I can integrate the three modules.

Comment: Hi check [http://dpaste.com/hold/751200/](http://dpaste.com/hold/751200/), i hope it answer most of your question.

Comment: thanks so much for this and sorry for the delay, I was travelling and just got back. I will try and understand your code today and try to implement this. Thanks again.